# Is there is a way/command to check if I can get the NPM server from my pc?

Tags: npm

Actually I'm having issues getting a package from NPM, it should be related to a proxy issue, anyway, I'd like to check if my connection is able to Download it before try to download.

Comment: You should always be able to reach the public npm repository if you have a working Internet connection. I would advise you to solve that particular connectivity problem.

Comment: Yes surely I will, but I'd like to automate that to avoid it. I guess there is no way to achieve this.

Comment: What else would you achieve with that? Even if there was a reason to check whether the repository is reachable, why not just issue the download operation and observe the outcome? It's not like solving the underlying problem is a bad idea.

Comment: Cuz I must to wait some minutes before the timeout